# How to set the time in phone7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can an application set the current time on a phone7 device? I can't seem to find any documentation about it but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: I have no idea, but I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't. The only way to set the device time is through the phone settings which are inaccessible from the WP7 API.